# Conditional probability in Bayesian analysis

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $X_i's$ are independent Poisson($\lambda_i$).

The $\lambda_i's$ have a prior distribution which is a mixture of $Gamma(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ and $Gamma(\alpha_2, \beta_2), i.e., pGamma(\alpha_1, \beta_1) + (1-p)Gamma(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$.

Let $Y_i$ iid $Bernoulli(p)$. If $Y_i = 1$, draw $\lambda_i$ from $Gamma(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$; if $Y_i = 0$, draw $\lambda_i$ from $Gamma(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$.

What is the conditional distribution of $Y_i=1$ given $X_i$ ?

Thanks!

Edit:
My initial thought is

- find the marginal distribution of $X_i, P(X_i)$ by finding the joint distribution of $X_i$ and $\lambda_i$ (using the mixture distribution of $\lambda_i$) and integrate over $\lambda_i$
- find the cond. dist. of $X_i$ given $Y_i = 1, P(X_i|Y_i=1)$ by finding the joint distribution of $X_i$ and $\lambda_i$ (here, the distribution of $\lambda_i$ is Gamma($\alpha_1, \beta_1$) only) and integrate over $\lambda_i$
- then the cond. dist. of $Y_i=1$ given $X_i$ is $p*P(X_i|Y_i=1)/P(X_i)$

Is this a valid way of approaching this question?

Comment: If this is related to an homework or exercise, please add the `self-study` tag and detail your attempt so far.

Comment: Hint: the conditional distribution of $Y_i$ given $X_i$ is the marginal of the conditional (or posterior) distribution of $(Y_i,\lambda_i)$ given $X_i$

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an ! Is it valid to find $(_|_=1)$ by first finding the joint distribution of $_$ and $\lambda_$ (here the distribution of $\lambda_$ is Gamma(1,1) only since $_=1$) and then integrate over $\lambda_$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct as well: find the joint conditional of $(X_i,\lambda_i)$ given $Y_i$ and integrate our $\lambda_i$.